# Unable to create view from existing table in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

command "show tables" is not showing view with name temp.

[image: ScreenShot of hive shell]

```
hive > SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false 
> create view temp as SELECT hour,id,regexp_replace(text,'\n','') as text FROM proj_tweets_2 
> ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

> Warning: Value had a \n character in it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Good of you to include the code as text. What is your question?

Comment: Do not comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: edit your question I find it very helpful when questions contain at least one explicit question - here *How do I get view temp created, and how do I check that?* comes to mind.

Comment: I gather that from hive 2.2.0, views are listed with [`SHOW VIEWS`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/AlterView) - do you have any indication the `create view temp` failed beyond `show tables` not listing it?

Comment: A view is a logical object, a Query on top of existing tables or views. It cannot be STORED AS ... and ROW FORMAT SERDE is also not applicable